# What approach should I use with Auth0 sms and email one time code

Tags: authentication, passwords, auth0, okta, one-time-password

I am currently using Auth0 to allow users to log in to an application. I am building it using the embedded approach. I see in the Auth0 documentation that they support passwordless login for SMS and email but I am not sure if that is the correct approach to use for a one time code when a user forgets their password?

Has anyone developed a forgot password and reset through embedded with Auth0? What approach did you use? Is passwordless strictly for logging in?

Important - this is not the universal login approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in Auth0 that user can be authenticated. Those are categorized under the [Connections](https://auth0.com/docs/identityproviders) in Auth0. Passwordless is one way of doing so. In this approach there is no password involved in. Which means, there can’t be a use-case, where the user forget his password for your application. (What can happen is that user forget his password for his email account or user would no longer have access to mobile phone, where he receive the SMS from Auth0 for authentication.) **So passwordless is not for reset user password. It is just for Authenticate the user.**

If you provide an option to login with Username and Password you can use Database connection type in Auth0. In this approach, there is a use-case where, user forget his password for your app. 
In that case your application should provide the forget password option. In Universal Login, it has built in support for this. However, as you don’t use Universal Login, you may have to implement that by yourself.There are couple of methods which are explained in [Auth0 Documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change). One options would be to use [change_password](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#change-password) endpoint in Authentication APIs. This will send an reset password email to user. Then user can use the link given in that email to reset his password. There is another option, where you can generate a password reset ticket in Auth0 using the [password reset ticket](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Tickets/post_password_change) endpoint. Hope you can use one of them for your requirement.